# What could a skeleton "bleed"?

Tags: science-based

I am developing a video game. For living creatures, when struck there is a bleeding effect, and I want to add an effect like bleeding to skeletons. Could I use acid as an alternative bleeding effect for bones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Blood

If you allow us to assume that skeletons are alive/recently alive, then there is no need to change anything. The bones in our bodies already have a lot of blood in them, as bone marrow generates all the blood in our bodies. While skeletons have less mass in general, they should bleed as much as a human (if not more) relative to their weight. When a skeleton is hit, the effect may be smaller, but it would still be there and would result in damage as normal.

As an addendum, it may be desirable to not have a bleeding effect for monsters where it doesn't make sense; consider that many "ice" monsters will have immunity to frost spells.

Answer (score 6):

**Dust**

Acid and bone is a bad combo!  Acid dissolves bone!  But old bones crumble to dust.  You could have dust coming off your wounded skeletons.  Dust would need to be animated different than blood because it would blow around, not just drizzle to the ground.  Maybe when you hit the skeleton a cloud of dust could come off, like the cloud of blood but white; then you could use the same animation for dust and blood.

Acid is good but it needs to be in something besides skeletons.

Comment: Killing them with acid would give smoke and a nice melting effect.. quite a challenge to render that in a game, but it would look spectacular !